# installing winehq-stable giving unmet dependencies error

Tags: wine, 22.04, dependencies

Im on ubuntu 22.04 and i tried installing wine. i followed all the steps on the website and it was good the repository was working but when i did
`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`
it gave me an error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.1~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help

Comment: What is "the website"? Unless you have a specific need for the latest version of wine, undo all you have done and install wine from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: winehq.org , i need the latest version because ubuntu 22.04 doesn't support older versions

Comment: I guarantee you Ubuntu 22.04 supports the version in its repos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems to install it.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

add 32-bit arch. Now we need the key for repo

```
wget -O- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
```

Then we add the repo for jammy.

```
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg] http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list
```

Now

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Gives on my System

```
wine --version
wine-7.0.1
```

Sidenote I have only mozillateam repo enabled (for firefox and thunderbird packages).
All other packages on my system from default repos.

[source](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-winehq-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/)